# "Blueprint" of the code for commercial software

Tags: architecture, uml, blueprint

I'm wondering what approaches are being used to "document" the architecture of a software in commercial enviroments? Is UML still using as I'm taught in the uni?

This question arises as I'm diving into dozens file of code and think there should be a better way to get the basic understanding of the code instead of wandering around the files?

Comment: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the level may vary, but UML is still very much used in the industry.

UML is a very "general purpose" modelling language. The last few years I noticed a rise in usage of the more specific modelling languages.

More often then not the different languages are being used next to each other. And although each modelling language is independent and doesn't know about the others, I often see that relationships are created between the different models and modelling languages to ensure a system wide traceability.

Below is a list of what I regularly encounter:

- Archimate/Togaf for architecture modelling
- BPMN for business process modelling
- UML for functional/technical analysis
- SysML for Systems engineering modelling.

Comment: Thanks, it is very enlightening...